# main page website availiable, but subpages give an 404 error

Tags: wordpress, nginx

A website within our management has a problem. The website works on the main page, but when we try to enter a link within the website we get an 404 error. 
The website is running on a VPS with the webservices apache and nginx (Nginx before apache).

We see the following error in the proxy_error_log when clicking on a link within the website:

```
2019/11/20 14:01:12 [error] 8488#0: *1507 "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/example2/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 92.111.x.x, server: example.com, request: "GET /example2/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com"
```

This is an wordpress site. The file index.php is not needed to load the website. We only need the permalink part ( examle.com/example2/ )

We tried the solutions of:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-and-nginx-404-errors-all-but-home-page

but none of them worked. Is there something else we can try.

**EDIT**

We fixed the problem by installing the following extension:
`htaccess to nginx`. That converted the default wordpress .htaccess to the following code:

```
 #ignored: "-" thing used or unknown variable in regex/rew
 if (!-f $request_filename){
          set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
  if (!-d $request_filename){
          set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
  if ($rule_1 = "21"){
          rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: please check permalinks. This issue might be of the permalinks. change permalink and then check again.

Comment: We tried to reset the permalinks, but we get the same error

Comment: In wordpress also Index.php is needed to load the site. please check this "https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/index.php". check your application folder structure.